# Storing Keras model HDF5 file to SQL database

Tags: python, sql, keras, byte, hdf5

I have a Keras Neural Network model that gets updated regularly.  For historical traceability, I would like to keep a copy of each trained model (architecture + weights + optimizer state) in a database.  [Keras will export an HDF5 file](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#savingloading-whole-models-architecture-weights-optimizer-state) that includes all of the information about the model.  Is there a way to convert this file into a format that could be stored in a SQL database record so that the full model could be retrieved/used later, even if that retrieval isn't super fast?

I am using Python3 to build/train the model and interact with the SQL database.  Also, I'm using MS SQL Server for the database if that makes a difference.

### Update:

Based on the comments, I am saving the HDF5 file and then reading that file back into Python like this:

```
filepath = 'C:\\path\\to\\file.h5'
model.save(filepath)
with open(filepath, "rb") as f:
    model_bytes = f.read()
```

When I try to `INSERT` the `model_bytes` value into a `VARBINARY(MAX)` column in MSSQL, I get the following error:

> pypyodbc.DataError: ('22018', '[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][SQL Server]Operand type clash: ntext is incompatible with
>   varbinary(max)')

Any ideas on how to preprocess the byte data type in Python so that it will insert correctly in SQL?

When I print `model_bytes` to screen it looks like this:

> b'\x89HDF\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x08\x00\x04\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff@\x13\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00`\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x88\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa8\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x08\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00TREE\x00\x00\x01\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00...

Comment: You can store the file in a `varbinary(max)` column. You should probably use the [Filetable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filetables-sql-server?view=sql-server-2014) to make file management easier, especially for large files

Comment: Is there any data transformation/preparation required before I call an SQL INSERT statement to upload the file to the `Filetable` with `varbinary(max)` column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to find a clean way to do this. The way I solved it was to store the file name/path in the database along with some meta-data about the model.  I stored the actual model (HDF5 file) in Google Cloud Storage.  So when I want to retrieve the model, I query the DB to get the latest filename, then I download it from Google Cloud Storage.